# Angular 7 why mat-checkbox blocks scrolling on a page

Tags: html, css, angular

There is such code in app.component.html

```
<mat-drawer-container>
    <mat-drawer class="medsu-sidenav" #sidenav mode="over"  position="end" [(opened)]="opened">
        <img ngClass="logo" [src]="'/images/full_logo.svg'">
        <img (click)="drawer.toggle()" ngClass="cross" [src]="'/images/cross-black.svg'">
        <div *ngFor="let item of menuItems" ngClass="menuItemList">
            <a href="{{item.href}}">
                <img ngClass="menuItemsImage" [src]="item.image">
                <span ngClass="menuItemsText">{{ item.text }}</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </mat-drawer>
    <div className="content">
      <app-header title='asdf'  #headerMain></app-header>
      <div class="main_outlet_content" [ngStyle]="{height:'calc(100vh - '+ mainRouterOutletHeight+ 'px)'}">
          <app-aside-dashboard></app-aside-dashboard>
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

app.component.css

```
.mat-drawer-container{
  height:100% !important;
}
.medsu-sidenav{
  width:320px;
  .logo{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:36px;
    margin-bottom:27px;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
  }
  .cross{
    margin-top: 13px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
  .menuItemsImage{
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:37px;
  }
  .menuItemList{
    margin-bottom:15px;
  }
  .menuItemsText{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #282828;
    text-decoration: none;
    a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active{
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
}
.main_outlet_content {
  display: flex;
  ::ng-deep > .ng-star-inserted{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
::ng-deep{
  .margin_static_bottom{
    margin-bottom: 24px;
  }
  .padding_custom_lf_rt{
    padding-left: 24px !important;
    padding-right: 24px !important;
  }
}
```

When there is a revalidation-component in the router-outlet that contains other components in itself, this happens. I open the revalidation page in the browser, this page has a scroll, it contains the menu items when pressed, other components open. First, scrolling works fine until when I click one of the menu items, which contains mat-checkbox and mat-radio-button, and then scrolling is blocked.

I tried to find the cause by the exception method and only in two conditions did the scrolling continue to work: either to comment on these mat elements or to remove this from this piece of code [ngStyle] = "{height: 'calc (100vh -' + mainRouterOutletHeight + 'px)'}"

```
<div className="content">
      <app-header title='asdf'  #headerMain></app-header>
      <div class="main_outlet_content" [ngStyle]="{height:'calc(100vh - '+ mainRouterOutletHeight+ 'px)'}">
          <app-aside-dashboard></app-aside-dashboard>
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I’ve been eating for several days to understand what’s wrong here, and I didn’t find anything that would help me fix this, please help me.

Comment: Can you add you minimal code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and provide us that helps us a lot resolving your problem

Comment: I'll try it now